# iPhone - Blank Screen when Switching VIews

Tags: iphone, memory, memory-management, uiviewcontroller

I have an application that makes use of drill-down views, tabbars, etc.  I'm also making use of the UIImagePicker, as well as Route-Me for mapping support.  Normally, the application performs fine.  However, I find that if I perform a lot of activities and then switch between views, I end up with a blank screen and my view is not drawn.  My hunch is this is memory related, but how can I be sure?  Has anyone encountered a similar situation?  How did you go about correcting it?  What can I look for?  Thanks for any help you can give!

Steve

Answer (score 0):

You're view is probably being unloaded in the background. If you have access to forums, here is a good thread:
https://devforums.apple.com/message/56191

Basically, you need to expect that while in another part of the application, iphone may unload a view which isn't active (see viewDidUnload method). When you switch to that view, it will then call viewDidLoad again.

Answer (score 0):

I had this exact problem... In the method that handles my UIView switching, I checked for ([newViewController.view superview] == nil) which it was during a blank-out! So I went and re-initted it using [[NewViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"NewView" bundle:nil]

Hope this helps!